# How does changing the display attribute in the styling of an element hide/show it?

Tags: html, css

I'm following [this](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp) tutorial on how to create a CSS dropdown menu. Currently the method stated does not use any JavaScript (only HTML and CSS). Here is the method suggested, excluding the color/background color/font/etc.

```css
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the Dropdown button appears, and when one hovers over it, the list items are shown. The only styling applied when an element is hovered over is

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

How does this work? (the w3schools tutorial did not describe the reasoning behind the display styling)

When I ran the above snippet, I was expecting the list items to be shown inline and then, when the button is hovered over, to be shown as a block under the button (thus I was expecting the list items to never be hidden). What is making these list items hidden by default?

Furthermore, if I am applying the `display: block` styling on the div element (the one with the class dropdown), then how come when I hover over the empty space still physically under the button, however to the right of the list text, the `display: block` styling is undone (and the list items vanish)? I would expect the div element to take up an area in the shape of a rectangle (where even hovering over the white part of the rectangle would trigger :hover). *

* I may need to clarify this entire part of my question, please say so if I need to.

Comment: can you attach a screenshot of how you need a dropdown

Comment: @Gowtham Did you see the snippet? The result from that html/css can be seen by pressing the "Run Code Snippet".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.dropdown-content` is hidden by default:

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}
```

The later rule overrides that and shows the content when the pointer hovers over the parent `.dropdown`:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

This rule applies to any `.dropdown-content` within a `.dropdown` that is in the `hover` state.

To answer the second question, it's because of the `position: absolute` that the white-space next to the child items don't maintain the hover state. See the snippet below, which includes outlines to show the boundaries of each element. As long as the pointer is within the blue (parent) box or the red (child) box, the hover state is maintained.

```css
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: solid 1px blue;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    outline: solid 1px red;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    display: block;
    background: yellow;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, I got the CSS seletors mixed up with the HTML classes. Could you also provide some information for my second question (about the div element and what area toggles :hover).